# Why is there a reference error? I believe I used the generic constructor and initialized the function correctly

Tags: c++

Create a class "init" The private section is a 10-element array of integers.  The public section has a generic constructor, init and print functions and an overload of the operator <.  X < Y means that for some i  between 0 and 9, the first i-1 elements are the same but the iTH element of X < the iTH element of Y.  In other words, the first time they differ in an element, the element in X < the element in Y.

[My code so far with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8okhS.png)

> If X = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Y = (1,2,3,4,5,9,8,0,1,12),  X < Y
>   If X = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Y = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),  X is not
>   less than Y

Comment: Post the code rather than posting an image of it.

Comment: The picture of your code doesn't define the constructor, post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the constructor for your class. You just declared it.

Either define it or use default keyword.

i.e.

```
    class seq10
    {
    public:
        seq10(){}; // or seq10() = default;
    ...
    };
    // or define outside
    seq10::seq10(){ ... }
```

Also, you seem to have arguments for your class member functions. Was that intentional? They also seem to share the same exact name as your private member variable. Just some advice, prepend your member variable name with 'm' i.e. 'm_a" if you want to use similar names. And probably use more expressive variables.

I believe you wanted to overload the init_seq10() with init_seq10(int a[]).
init_seq10(int a[]) should just copy the array into the private member array rather than use cin since you already provided input.
i.e.

```
    init_seq10(){  for( array ){ cin >> a[i] } }
    init_seq10( int a[] ){ std::copy( begin(a), end(a), begin(m_a) ) }
```

Another bit of advice, if you are using c++11 onwards you can just use range loops.
e.g.

```
    for( auto const& elem : m_a ){ cout << elem << " "; }
```